# Matrix calculation from an equation

Tags: matrices

I am trying to find matrix y from an equation

For example, I know (python)

```
>>> x = matrix([[5,1],[2,4]])
>>> y = matrix([[1,5],[3,3]])
>>> print x
[[5 1]
 [2 4]]
>>> print y
[[1 5]
 [3 3]]
>>> print x*y % 7
[[1 0]
 [0 1]]
```

Assuming, I don't know what y is. But I know xy = I mod7 
How do I calculate y?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let 
$$
y=\begin{pmatrix} a & b\\ c& d\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Then $XY$ sets up some equations:
\begin{align}
5a+c &\equiv 1\,\, (\operatorname{mod} 7)\\
5b+d &\equiv 0\,\, (\operatorname{mod} 7)\\
2a+4c &\equiv 0\,\, (\operatorname{mod} 7)\\
2b+4d &\equiv 1\,\, (\operatorname{mod} 7).
\end{align}

You can solve this like you would solve any system of equations, only you have to remember to take every thing $\operatorname{mod} 7$.  For example, take the second equation and multiply it by $4$ to get:
$$
20b+4d \equiv 0\,\, (\operatorname{mod} 7).
$$
But, $20\equiv 6\,\,(\operatorname{mod} 7)$. So, this becomes
$$
6b+4d \equiv 0\,\, (\operatorname{mod} 7).
$$
Then subtract fourth equation from this to get:
$$
4b \equiv -1\,\, (\operatorname{mod} 7).
$$
But, $-1\equiv 6\,\,(\operatorname{mod} 7)$.  From above $b\equiv 5\,\,(\operatorname{mod} 7)$.  Now substitute $b$ into those equations and just keep going.

I'm not sure what you are comfortable with, but the integers mod $7$ are a field. So, all this works.

Comment: I get the idea thanks! Can you also tell me if there I can code this in perl/python preferably?

Comment: @Omair: There may be a way, but I don't know.

Comment: Do these equations become like this, which is unsolvable?
5a      +  c      - 7e = 1
   + 5b      +  d - 7f = 0
2a      + 4c      - 7g = 1
2b           + 4d - 7h = 0

Comment: You wouldn't need to substitute in the $7e$, $7f$, etc.  You can solve them using modular arithmetic.

Comment: Sorry for asking so many questions. But, can you give an example on how you would solve the above to get y?

Comment: @Omair.: I have edited in more work.  I also fixed a couple of errors in my initial equations.  I accidentally switched a $0$ with a $1$.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to know how to do arithmetic $\pmod 7$.

For example:
adding: $4 + 5 \equiv 2 \pmod 7$
multiplying : $4 \cdot 5 \equiv 6 \pmod 7$
subtracting: $4 - 5 \equiv 6\pmod 7$
dividing: $4 / 5 \equiv 5 \pmod 7$

Most of those should be obvious, you might have to do some studying to learn how to do modular division (sometimes called modular inverse).

Then all you have to do is solve the matrix like you normally would, except substitute the modular arithmetic for the regular arithmetic that you are used to.  You just use basic Gaussian elimination.  When you multiply a row by a constant, multiply each element $\pmod 7$.  When you add 2 rows, add them using modular arithmetic.

It is not a coincidence that all matrix operations work if you use modular arithmetic instead of regular arithmetic.  They are actually fundamentally defined that way.